# Diffie–Hellman key exchange and Discrete Log

Tags: encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I have a general question, and for that I will give an example: 
assuming Alice and Bob chose the prime number 593 and a public g= 9 .
Alice choose the number 530. 
Bob choose the number 147.

Alice computes: x= g^a mod p = 574
Bob computes: y = g^b mod p = 527
Their shared key is 156

Now Eve is trying to crack the key and find a. She has a cracking function, and she finds c such that: g^c mod p =x 
In our exmaple, c = 234, but this is not the original a that Alice chose, so she still didn't succeed. My question is: is there a way she finds out the original a of Alice, using this information- that Eve has c, g, p  and x, and she knows that g^c mod p =x

(Maybe by inverse function, I don't know..)
Thanks

Comment: if you have the wrong key, you'll still be able to "decrypt" the cyphertext, but end up with garbage instead of the original plaintext

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic crypto, without any particular programming.

Comment: @MarcBdo you mean that Eve cannot get the original a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If

> g^a mod p = g^x mod p

Then

> g^ab mod p = g^xb mod p

In particular

> (g^b mod p)^a mod p= (g^b mod p)^x mod p

So you can, for all practical purposes, pretend that Alice's private key is x. 
This is why it is important for g to be a generator of the group, so that there 
are no such 'sibling' private keys.

She can't know the 'original' a, but she does know that it's in the (usually)
small set of numbers that differ from x by multiples of o(g). Which one it is doesn't
really matter.

In this particular case, what's happening is that `g` is of order `296` instead of `592`. Because of this, the actual secret key Alice chose - `530`, has a 'sibling':

> c = 530 + 296 mod 592 = 234

Comment: If I understood correctly, she can crack the shared key of Bob and Alice right?